# How to localize DatatableActionDropdownDefaultText and other elements from ui.shared.theme DataTable-Extensions,js

Tags: abp

THe ABPIdentity module on my project will not localize the various datatable elements such as the pager buttons, the processing message and DatatableActionDropdownDefaultText dropdown.  I can see from the code that its using AbpUi as the localization resource but its not able to resolve to the main localization file of my project.
I tried adding "AbpUi:DatatableActionDropdownDefaultText" : "Action" in my main en.json file and it would not resolve.

This is MVC/Razor Pages project.

[Unresolved Element Localization Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szQUj.png)

Comment: Hello, you are creating the button using `<abp-table>`, right?